linear functions in a bounded region
Problem:
Consider a triangle $PQR$ in $R^2$. Let $A$ be a point lying on triangle $PQR$
or in the region enclosed by it. Prove that, for any function $f(x, y) =
ax + by + c$ on $R^2$,
$f(A) \le max (f(P), f(Q), f(R))$
My attempt:
As we can easily see the locus of all the points having same value of this function, is a line  and the slope of this line is always $-a/b$ but if this line does not intersect $x$ axis then the maximum value must occur at the three vertices only because it is independent of $x$, extreme values of $y$ occur at vertices only. Now if it intersects $x$ axis, then moving the line along $x$ axis must only increase or decrease the value of $f(x)$, and thus again maximum must occur at vertices only.
I have a strong intuition that moving the line along $x$ axis must only increase or decrease the value of $f(x)$, which can be seen easily by putting y=0 but it appears as if this means that the maximum value of $f(x)$ must occur at points with extremal values of x which is not true for every case, hence this solution does not seem true to me. So, please help me with this.

This problem was asked in a high school mathematics contest, so please dont use higher mathematics

You don't need to consider the $x$ or $y$ axis in any of this, but your thought about lines of constant value is good.
Consider, in particular, the line $f(x, y) = f(A)$, i.e. the line of constant value of $f$ passing through $A$. Outside of some degenerate cases it must:

Intersect the triangle's boundary at two points

Divide the plane into two regions - one where $f > f(A)$, and one where $f < f(A)$.


Can you then say something about how many of $P, Q, R$ are on either side of this line?

So the line f(x,y)=f(A) will divide the triangular region into two regions, one where f>=f(A) and one where f<f(A), and thus as the region f>=f(A)  must at least contain one of the vertex of the triangle, otherwise A would be outside the region, the inequality is proved. Do you mean the same?

Yes, that's what I'm getting at, although depending on the context you might need to make the proof a little tighter (and also consider whether there are any edge cases to prove separately).
